# convergence methodology is not clear to me

Tags: bonobo-etl

It would be great if something like this could be make to work. It is not clear to me how to implement convergence at the moment unless I use raw input and embed the name of the incoming edge that is 'ticking' into the payload.

```py
import bonobo
from bonobo.config import Configurable
from bonobo.config import use_context

@use_context
class A(Configurable):

    def __call__(self, context):
        context.set_output_fields(['a'])
        yield {'a': 'a'}

@use_context
class B(Configurable):

    def __call__(self, context, a):
        context.set_output_fields(['b'])
        yield {'b': 'b'}

@use_context
class F(Configurable):

    def __call__(self, context):
        context.set_output_fields(['f'])
        yield {'f': 'f'}

@use_context
class G(Configurable):

    def __call__(self, context, f):
        context.set_output_fields(['g'])
        yield {'g': 'g'}

@use_context
class Normalize(Configurable):

    def __call__(self, context, b, f):
        context.set_output_fields(['n'])
        yield {'n': 'n'}



if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = Normalize()
    graph = bonobo.Graph()
    # Here we mark _input to None, so normalize won't get the "begin" impulsion.
    graph.add_chain(n, _input=None)

    # Add two different chains
    graph.add_chain(A(), B(), _output=n)
    graph.add_chain(F(), G(), _output=n)


    bonobo.run(graph)
```

Currently this code will result in an error that is understandable, but unfortunate:

```
 bonobo.errors.UnrecoverableTypeError  Input of <__main__.Normalize object at 0x00000261F76EDD30> does not bind to the node signature.
                                        Args: (<NodeExecutionContext(+Normalize) in=1>,)
                                        Input: Bag(b={'b': 'b'})
                                        Kwargs: {}
                                        Signature: (context, b, f)
 - A in=1 out=1 [done]
 - B in=1 out=1 [done]
 - F in=1 out=1 [done]
 - G in=1 out=1 [done]
 ! Normalize in=1 err=1 [defunct]
```